# Postgres hide and show database rows based on some condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Thank you in advance for your response.

I have on requirement where admin can create some rows in table. We have lots of clients. This data created by admin is by default applicable to all the clients. Client can create a specific data which will be applicable to this client only and not visible for other clients. How ever client can disable some records created by the admin. If client disables record then this record will be disabled only for this client and not for the other clients.

Lets take an example we have project type as a data here and we have client-1 and client-2.
If admin creates project-type-1 and project-type-2 then both these types will be visible in drop down for client-1 and client-2.

If client-1 adds project-type-3 then all the three project-types will be appear for client-1.

If client-2 disables project-type-1 which is created by admin then in this case project-type-2 will be only applicable for client-2.

following are some certain conditions.

1. When admin soft delete any global project-type then this will not appear for any client although it is opted by client.
2. When admin creates any new project type then I don't want it to be add for each and every client automatically in database as row.
3. Client cannot create the project-type having same name as created by admin.
4. For any client project type should be unique.

It would be great if you can provide me some sql to how Create/Read/Update/Delete sql queries for admin and client.

Comment: Please provide the database table design

Comment: Please also provide sample data for each table - as text **no images** and the expected results for that data (should contain admin created items and each customer created items). You may want to review [ask].